# Uniform used in shader is inactive

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I have the following shaders:
My fragment shader:

```
#version 110
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;


void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

And my vertex shader:

```
#version 110

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

attribute vec3 vertex;

void main() {
    vec4 world =  modelMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1);
    vec4 camera = world * viewMatrix;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * world;
}
```

They both compile and link just fine. When I print out my active uniforms I get

```
projectionMatrix
modelMatrix
```

but no viewMatrix. When I try and get the Uniform with glGetUniformLocation, I can get projectionMatrix, modelMatrix, and my vertex attribute just fine, so why is viewMatrix inactive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in the last line of your vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * world;
```

You probably meant `projectionMatrix * camera`.  Otherwise, the GLSL compiler sees that `camera` isn't being used and optimizes it away, which means that `viewMatrix` is no longer being used either.  Unused uniforms are not considered active, which leads to your predicament.

Note: Your viewing transform is also backwards.  You probably want `vec4 camera = viewMatrix * world`.

Comment: Thanks for the notification about my view transform being backwards, I forgot that matrix multiplication was not commutative

Comment: `glPosition = projectionMatrix * camera` would be eqivalent to `glPosition = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1)`, which is what you are calculating.  Note that although the combined matrices are often referred to as MV, MVP, etc, the actual order of multiplication is `P*V*M`.